# How to create URL to be shared with others

Tags: java, url, survey

i'm building an application that generates surveys, the code is going to be written in Java.
Once the user is done creating their survey, they must have a link to share with other people who will fill this survey. 
I don't have a clear idea how to implement this, like, should i create a new web page for each survey and give the user its url which will be forwarded to other users who will fill this survey or there is another (smarter) mechanism to do that? if so, any idea on how to implement the solution?

Comment: This is an extremely large question. There are a lot of pieces to this, and from the looks of it you haven't put in a lot of your own effort trying things out yet. We prefer you to have made your own attempts to solve this and have questions from there, not look to us to solve your problem for you.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded like being lazy or anything.
I wasn't asking for code, just a mechanism to implement myself or an API to work with. that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're saving surveys somewhere, be it database or a file.

So the easiest way is to give a user a link like this: `www.mysurvey.com/survey?id=surveyID`, where `surveyId` is a primary key of survey's main record in the DB, or a filename if you use files.

That obviously leads us to security problem: if user is a smart one, he or she can get *other* surveys guessing the id, or, worse yet, retrieve system files playing with filename. But for a simple example this will work, and this will get you started.

Comment: A simple workaround would be using random GUIDs as survey IDs. The chance of the user guessing a valid ID would be negligible.

Comment: @Inerdial Well, there are tons of approaches, starting with a salted hash and never ending :) I just don't think it's the time when OP is interested in dirty details.

Comment: @alf so I should create standard web page, and then get the survey's survey's id from the URL, fetch the data that correspond to that id and display it in that web page?

Comment: @MohamedTurki I'm afraid I don't know what "standard page" is. Usually you write a handler for URL, be it a Servlet, Action, Handler, Controller or whatever your framework uses.

Comment: Sorry, i just lacked the proper term for that. Now I have a clearer idea of how things should work.Thanks